# What is the best way to control the flow of the child processes in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run, pause and terminate the child processes in Python from the parent process. I have tried to use `multiprocessing.Value` but for some reason the parent process never finishes completely although I `terminate` and `join` all the processes. My use case is something like:

```
def child(flow_flag):
   while True:
      with flow_flag.get_lock():
          flag_value = flow_flag.value
      if flag_value == 0:
         print("This is doing some work")
      elif flag_value == 1:
         print("This is waiting for some time to check back later")
         time.sleep(5)
      else:
         print("Time to exit")
         break

def main():
    flow_flag = Value('i', 0)
    processes  = [Process(target=child, args=(flow_flag,)) for i in range(10)]
    [p.start() for p in processes]    
    print("Waiting for some work")
    with flow_flag.get_lock():    
        flow_flag.value = 1
    print("Do something else")
    with flow_flag.get_lock():    
        flow_flag.value = 0
    print("Waiting for more work")
    with flow_flag.get_lock():    
        flow_flag.value = 2
    print("Exiting")
    for p in processes:
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

This never finishes properly and I have to `Ctrl+C` eventually. Then I see this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abcde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1308, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What is a better way? FYI, while waiting for something else, I am spawning some other processes. I also had them not terminating properly, and I was using `Value` with them too. It got fixed when I switched to using `Queue` for them. However, `Queue` does not seem to be appropriate for the case above.

P.S. : I am ssh'ing into Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT: After a lot of debugging, not exiting turned out to be because of a library I am using that I did not suspect to cause this. My apologies for false alarm. Thanks for the suggestions on the better way of controlling the child processes.

Comment: I needed to add a few lines to make the example running code, but it worked for me on ubuntu 19.10 - 18.04 should be no different. I also removed `terminate` assuming you'd want work in progress to continue and it sill worked. Can you add the bits that make this a working example and post that so we know we are doing the same thing?

Comment: After a lot of debugging, this turned out to be because of a library I am using that I did not suspect to cause this. My apologies for false alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works for me, but let me chime in on "is there another way". Instead of polling at 5 second intervals you could create a shared event object that lets the child processes know when they can do their work. Instead of polling for Value 1, wait for the event.

```
from multiprocessing import *
import time
import os

def child(event, times_up):
    while True:
        event.wait()
        if times_up.value:
            print(os.getpid(), "time to exit")
            return
        print(os.getpid(), "doing work")
        time.sleep(.5)

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    event = manager.Event()
    times_up = manager.Value(bool, False)
    processes  = [Process(target=child, args=(event, times_up)) for i in range(10)]
    [p.start() for p in processes]
    print("Let processes work")
    event.set()
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Make them stop")
    event.clear()
    time.sleep(4)
    print("Make them go away")
    times_up.value = True
    event.set()
    print("Exiting")
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.7.7 running on FreeBSD 12.1 (64-bit) I cannot reproduce your problem.

After fixing the indentation and adding the necessary imports The changed program runs fine AFAICT.

BTW, you might want to `import sys` and add

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)
```

to the beginning of your `main()`.